# Rounding Error when converting from character to numeric

Tags: r, time, timestamp, type-conversion, numeric

I have a data.table of data numbers in character format that I am trying to convert to numeric numbers. However the issue is that the numbers are very long and I want to retain all of the numbers without any rounding from R. For examle the first 5 elements of the data.table:

```
> TimeO[1]
[1] "20110630224701281482"
> TimeO[2]
[1] "20110630224701281523"
> TimeO[3]
[1] "20110630224701281533"
> TimeO[4]
[1] "20110630224701281548"
> TimeO[5]
[1] "20110630224701281762"
```

I wrote a function to convert from a character into numeric:

```
convert_time_fast <- function(tim){  
  b <- tim - tim%/%10^12*10^12
  # hhmmssffffff
  ms <- b%%10^6; b <-(b-ms)/10^6
  ss <- b%%10^2; b <-(b-ss)/10^2
  mm <- b%%10^2; hh <-(b-mm)/10^2
  # if hours>=22, subtract 24 (previous day)
  hh <- hh - (hh>=22)*24
  return(hh+mm/60+ss/3600+ms/(3600*10^6))
}
```

However the rounding occurs in R so datapoints now have the same time. See first 5 elements after converting:

```
TimeOC <--convert_time_fast(as.numeric(TimeO))
> TimeOC[1]
[1] 1.216311
> TimeOC[2]
[1] 1.216311
> TimeOC[3]
[1] 1.216311
> TimeOC[4]
[1] 1.216311
> TimeOC[5]
[1] 1.216311
```

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should test to see if they are really equal (`all.equal()`).
Usually R limits the number of digits it prints (usually to 7), but they are still there.

See also this example:

```
> as.numeric("1.21631114")
[1] 1.216311
> as.numeric("1.21631118")
[1] 1.216311
> all.equal(as.numeric("1.21631114"), as.numeric("1.21631118"))
[1] "Mean relative difference: 3.288632e-08" # which indicates they're not the same
```

Comment: The issue is that I am trying to graph the data points and the points with the same time are being drawn on top of one another

Comment: When I do all.equal it says TRUE so I think there is an issue in the actual conversion function

Comment: I am having this problem too. Converting characters (with many decimal places) to numeric. Losing decimal places and subsequent problems. Massive upvote for anyone with an answer. :-)